# GitHub repo clone empty

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, git-checkout

I tried to clone a private repo from GitHub to Android Studio using "Check out Project from Version Control" The cloning works. However, after cloning, the Android directory is empty. I couldn't find any Java files in the Project directory either:

[image]

[image]

Comment: there's only master branch

Comment: Try to reopen the project, using the Android studio wizard, the one that appears when you doesn't have any open projects; select import non Android studio project and select the local folder you just cloned (even if the one versioned was an Android studio project)

Comment: You're trying to clone a private repository so make sure the account you're using has the permission needed to clone that repository. Also check your global settings maybe another account is being used for the cloning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with the IDE.

### ***`How to fix it?`***

1. Close the project.
2. Delete the `.idea` folder
3. Open the studio again
4. Create new project from existing source - your project path

And thats it :-)

Comment: In #4, I opened the existing project instead of creating a new project from existing source. It worked. Thanks!